# problem with disconnected pattern in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

i have applied pattern from swatch in illustrator
but i figured out that some part of the pattern is disconnected
how do i fix this problem?[image]

Comment: What is your Illustrator version?

Answer (score 1):

Ok.

I think your Ai version is CS5.

I made your pattern the way it must be done.

This way it won't have any problem.

See the image below:

[image]